# Why using setter or field key in entity constructor gives different results?

Tags: php

Here is a dump of a new instance of my entity `Theme`, when using `$this->type = 'theme';` in the `__construct` function.

```
ExplorerController.php on line 197:
Theme {#450 ▼
  -id: null
  -headings: ArrayCollection {#449 ▶}
  -infos: null
  -base: null
  -deletedAt: null
  -key: null
  -description: null
  -type: null
  +"type": "theme"
}
```

I don't understand why the last field **type** appears twice, first with a `null` value, and then between quotes with a "plus" sign in front.

If I use the setter `$this->setType('theme');` then the result is as expected:

```
ExplorerController.php on line 197:
Theme {#450 ▼
  -id: null
  -headings: ArrayCollection {#449 ▶}
  -infos: null
  -base: null
  -deletedAt: null
  -key: null
  -description: null
  -type: "theme"
}
```

I guess it has to do with proxies, but this a subject I don't fully understand.

Could someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Can you provide us the code of your entity please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A dash in front of `type` indicates it's a private member.
- A plus indicates a public member.

By explicitly setting `$this->type`, you are setting the public member.

Without actually seeing your code, I cannot offer any other advice except to make sure you are not defining `$type` twice (maybe in an extended class or trait?).

Comment: My class `Entity` inherits the field "type" from a **mapped super class**. But it's not defined twice, and the behaviour is as expected when using the setter in the `__construct` function. (see my edit)

Comment: Property _defined_ once (in the parent class), but in the child class you add property with same name. In the child class you have not access to private properties of the parent, so when you set `$this->type` in the child, you add new dynamic property (with the same name 'type').

Comment: Thanks ClickLabs and @Timurib for making me understand my (very stupid) mistake: fields in my parent Class vere `private`, not `protected`.